# upload image when creating face event with graph api php

Tags: php, facebook

I dont seem to be able to get this to work. The event loads fine but the image just doesnt upload, please let me know what I am doing wrong, I thiink there is a problem with the picture url format, does in need the @ in front?, I have tried it without and it doesn't work:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
require 'facebook.php';
// appId and secret all work fine
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '************',
    'secret' => '**************',
    'fileUpload' => true
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $response = $facebook->api(
            "/me/events",
            "POST",
            array (
                'name' => $title,
                'start_time' => $start_time,
                'location' => $location,
                'end_time' => $end_time,
                'description' => $description,
                'picture' => '@http://andyotto.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/donald-    duck.gif?w=863',                
                'venue' => $venue
            )
        );
        if (count($response)>0){
            $response_message = "Event successfully added uploaded to Facebook.";
        }else{
            $response_message = "There was a problem uploading your event to Facebook.";
        }
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}


if ($user) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
    $statusUrl = $facebook->getLoginStatusUrl();
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope'=>'create_event'
    ));
    header( 'Location:'.$loginUrl ) ; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the docs that you can't upload an image directly once you publish an Event (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/events/#publish), at least the picture filed is not described.

According to this doc (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event#picture) you can set the Event's picture once it's created via

```
POST /{EVENT_ID}/picture
```

with the picture encoded as "multipart/form-data" in the request's body parameter "source".

Comment: Instead of `source` you can use the `url` parameter, with the HTTP URL of a publicly available picture as value (less hassle than building a `multipart/form-data` request).